# Read in from multiple type files all in different locations

Tags: c#, streamreader

In C# using StreamReader, I have to extract the data from multiple files. Here's the code I have so far. It's not exactly correct and I have to be more specific with it and add more to it yet. I need to select various individual files based on a date and time they all have in common. So only the files with a common inputted date and time will be selected for extraction. The problem is the files are different types e.g. text, xml and html and they may possible be in different locations. I have to display all the extracted data together. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("D:\\path", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".txt") || s.EndsWith(".xml"));

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("files")).
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    lbDisplay.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong
            MessageBox.Show("The file could not be read: ");
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be more specific with your question. Have you troubles reading an xml-File or a html-file? What does mean "display together"? How do you intend to display the result? In a unformatted textbox, as rich text, in a word document, others...? Why is "different places" a problem? Is `File.ReadAllLines` not good enough?

Comment: The StreamReader is to read from a stream. A file is not a stream - use the FileStream class to create a stream around A SINGLE file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileStream(v=vs.110).aspx (you cannot create a stream that points to multiple files)

Comment: Hi. I can read from one file no problem. What I am trying to do is read from multiple files and display the data in each by outputting it all together in the label. It doesn't really matter what it's displayed in, whether a textbox or label, the problem is displaying data from multiple files together.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I didn't realise that a Stream couldn't point to different files.

Comment: Yeah and I was wrong, the StreamReader can read files indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    IEnumerable<string> fileContents = Directory.EnumerateFiles("E:", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
            .Where(x => x.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) || x.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
            .Where(x => x.Extension == ".xml" || x.Extension == ".txt")
            .Select(file => ParseFile(file));

    private string ParseFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
        {
            string line;
            string endResult;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Logic here to determine if this is the correct file and append accordingly
                endResult += line + Environment.Newline;
            }
            return endResult;
        }
    }
```

This will get you a list of files then pass the FileInfo object to a method to read the contents, which is where you will need to add your logic to determine if you have the correct file. If so, then start appending your lines to the lblDisplay.

Comment: Hi IdahoSixString. Thank you but I'm sorry I must not have explained properly. The DateTime is within the file itself, not the creation dateTime of the file.

Comment: This will help you get the list of files first. Then you will need to open each file itself and read the contents of it to check if you have the correct information. I will update my answer shortly to show a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you IdahoSixString. This helps! :-)

Comment: ParseFile doesn't return a string.

Comment: @YairNevet Now it returns a string

Answer (score 1):

Use @IdahoSixString's answer to get the files

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(...
```

Now iterate them and get the lines of each of them

```
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files) {
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileInfo.FullName)) {
        lbDisplay.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

No StreamReaders or FileReaders, no testing for end of file, no explicit opening or closing of files.

---

If the different locations (folders) of the files are known to you, store them in an array and add a loop

```
var folders = new string[] { "C:\folder1", "C:\folder2", ... };
foreach (string folder in folders) {
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Select(... ;
    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in files) {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileInfo.FullName)) {
            lbDisplay.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oliver. Thank you but this is throwing up a few errors for me with the foreach adn File.ReadLines(files) such as  'Cannot convert type System.IO.FileInfo to string' and 'The best overloaded method match for System.IO.File.ReadLines (string) has some invalid arguments'.

Comment: If the `Directory.EnumerateFiles(...` gives you FileInfos instead of strings, write `File.ReadLines(file.FullName)` instead. (I updated the code examples)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you want to extract the file information (creation date, etc).

Use the FileInfo class for this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Based on your comments, the information is actually within the file. There's no magic here: you must open each file, one after the other, and parse its content to find the information you need. If it's an XML file, there are various classes in C# that can help you with it, such as the [XMLReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for commenting. I actually want to extract all the information but the file or files I target are based on a common Date and Time. So I need to be able to read a date and time from them and then select them and display all of their data combined. There is an additional difficulty in that they may be in different locations. So, I'm a bit stuck!

Comment: Are the different locations known, or do you need a search algorithm to search folders recursively?

Comment: If the date/time you're looking for is inside the file's content, and you're not referring about the file's creation date, then you must open and parse each file one after the other, and store the data you need before closing each file.

Comment: Hi Oliver, the location of the various files will be known to me.

Comment: Hi Joe, Yes the date time is within the files content. Thank you.